# What triggers a refill for the Special Delivery Chest in Gorhart?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Right now, my character is level 10. In all these levels, I've only had items in the Gorhart Special Delivery Chest once near the beginning of the game. I've checked it a few times since then and it's always empty. What triggers this chest to refill? Is it level or deed based? Or is it random?

Comment: I think it's just the "Get your DLC from here" bucket.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Do you know if the stuff I got at the beginning was DLC? It was the Shepard's entire set. I don't remember downloading anything...

Comment: You unlocked it by playing the demo. It's *technically* DLC, just DLC you didn't have to buy.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I actually didn't play the demo :/ Other ideas?

Comment: Must be the DLC that you get from connecting to an EA / Origin account then?

Comment: @RavenDreamer could be, I did do that.

Comment: @RavenDreamer That would explain why I got it. I was confused, thinking I shouldn't have gotten it since I didn't play the demo. I do like the Mass Effect look of the armor though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the Special Delivery Chest is to get you items that you earn out of game.

This includes, but is probably not limited to the following:

- Buying the game new (earn Shepard's Battle Armor set)
- Playing the demo (earn a weapon and helmet)
- Pre-order bonus (depends on where you bought the game)
- Playing the Mass Effect 3 demo (Omniblade daggers)